# Angular - Possible to apply a directive conditionally?

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-directive

I need to create two different `ul` depending on `type`. If I have the type of `first`, then I want to apply the directive `*dropdownMenu`. Otherwise, there will be no directive for dropdown.

Is it possible to apply the directive conditionally so that there will be no duplicated code ?

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="type === 'first'">
      <ul *dropdownMenu item-directive [firstLevelItems]="items1" [secondLevelItems]="items2" [type]="type">
      </ul>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container *ngIf="type !== 'first'">
      <ul item-directive [firstLevelItems]="items1" [secondLevelItems]="items2" [type]="type">
      </ul>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Angular 2+, there is no way to apply directive based on conditionally.
So need to duplicate code as you mentioned.

Comment: Since I couldn't find any workaround, I accept this as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass argument to your directive (assuming that its your one). Something like.

```
<ul *dropdownMenu="type"></ul>

@Directive({ selector: '[dropdownMenu]' })
export class DropdownMenuDirective implements OnInit {
    private _type: string;
    
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
    ) {}

    @Input()
    set dropdownMenu(type: string) {
        this._type = type
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this._type === 'first') {
            this.viewContainer.clear() // to clear the view
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef); // to create it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the directive belongs to ngx-bootstrap dropdown module. So, I am not able to play with the internal structure.